# How to send a post request with the result of a command or a script using curl?

Tags: bash, curl, request, ifconfig

I want to send a post request using the `curl` command with the data resulting from an execution of a script or command, in this case, the command is `ifconfig`. I am looking for a oneliner that can be executed in a Linux terminal or Windows CMD.

In simple words, I want to send the result of the command to the server.

Comment: You may need to use command substitution https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

Use command substation to redirect output of one command as input to another.

For e.g. ping ``echo localhost`` -c 3 ping ip 127.0.0.1 3 times

Comment: Not able to make it work for the curl command. I can't get my head around how should i pass the result in any form through curl, i don't want to save the context of command into  a file and then send it via curl.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the data to `curl`'s standard input, and use `-d @/-` to tell curl to read the dat from standard input.

It's common for command line utilities to use `-` to represent standard input.  Curl is one such utility.

In curl, `-d @something` will expect to get its data from path `something`.

So `-d @-` tells `curl` to get its POST data from standard input.

You can then pipe the data you want to upload straight to `curl`:

```
% echo "I am command output" | curl https://httpbin.org/anything -X POST -d @-
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "I am command output": ""
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length": "19",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.79.1",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6311155b-65b7066163f6fd4f050f1cd6"
  },
  "json": null,
  "method": "POST",
  "origin": "64.188.162.105",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This command worked for me

> 

```
curl -X POST -d "$(any command here)" https://XXXX.XXX
```

, but it only works for UNIX or Linux, not for Windows CMD or PowerShell. Please Comment if you know how to make it work for CMD and PS.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X POST url
-H 'Content-Type: text/plain'
-d 'Your Response'
```

If the url was to a PHP script the script to get the data would simply be:

```
$command = file_get_contents('php://input');
exec($command);
```

The Content-Type is what put the -d data in the request body.

Or you could use form data

```
curl -X POST url
-d 'response=Your Response'
```

The a PHP script would be

```
$command = $_POST['response'];
```